# deleting row from a csv file using sed and save the file without deleted row

Tags: bash, sed

I have a csv file from which I want to delete the second row using unix sed command.

The file.csv is represented below

```
a
b
c
d
```

so it becomes newfile.csv

```
a
c
d
```

Based on my search for solutions, the simplest way to do this seems to be using the following sed command;

`sed '2d' file.csv > newfile.csv`

Yet, the newfile.csv contains the deleted row

```
d
```

, not the expected

```
a
c
d
```

I am using iTerm2 on  macOS Mojave

Comment: Is it possible that file.csv has DOS line endings (CRLF)?  Do a `cat -e file.csv` and make sure you don't see any `^M` characters before the `$`s.

Comment: You are right. There are such characters

Comment: `dos2unix file.csv && sed '2d' file.csv > newfile.csv`

Comment: I had used dos2unix but did not remove it. I will try to remove them by hand. Actually, the file was in a mac csv format, which caused the problem. By saving it with plain csv, the problem was solved and the code worked. Thanks

Comment: You can use sed to remove those characters, but it's a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

In those cases, awk is useful, too:

```
$ awk 'NR != 2' file.csv
a
c
d
```

There awk prints every row but the number 2.

If it is easier to understand:

```
$ cat file.csv | awk 'NR != 2'
a
c
d
```

Comment: nope. The problem remains. This code just prints the removed row, like the one above

Comment: Your original `sed` command should work fine, it's almost certain you have some unexpected control characters hiding in your file. What does `cat -e file.csv` return for you?

Answer (score 0):

Possible the formatting of your file is wrong, try this:

```
dos2unix file.csv
```

then one of these

```
sed '2d' file.csv
awk 'NR!=2' file.csv
```